# Parsing letters with macron e.g ā when scraping a web page using lxml

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

Getting this error when trying to parse words in Te Reo Maori

Pāngarau - I am assuming its the macron

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0101'

Any ideas on how to sort this out?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/qualifications-standards/qualifications/ncea/subjects/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

text = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mainPage"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a')

print text[0].text
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/Teacher/Documents/Python/Standards/rip_html2.py", line 10, in <module>
    print text[0].text
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0101' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that triggered this error, be it the lxml related methods.  If possible post the traceback, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python2, lxml sometimes [returns `str`s, and sometimes `unicode`](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-does-lxml-sometimes-return-str-values-for-text-in-python-2) when you inspect an Element's `text` attribute.

It returns a `str` when the text is composed entirely of ascii characters, but it returns a `unicode` otherwise.

At the point where the error occurs, `text[0].text` is a `unicode` containing the character `u'\u0101'`.

To fix the error, explicitly encode the `unicode` to a byte string before printing:

```
print(text[0].text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Note that `utf-8` is just one of many [encodings you could use](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

---

Usually, if you are printing to a terminal, Python will detect the encoding used by the terminal, and use that encoding to encode `unicode` thus printing the bytes to the terminal.

Since you are getting the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0101' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

it appears you might be printing to a file, or Python was unable to determine the encoding of the output device. Since output devices only accept bytes (never unicode), all unicode must be encoded. In such cases Python2 automatically attempts to encode the `unicode` using the `ascii` codec. Hence the error.

See also: the [PrintFails wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails)

Answer (score -1):

It might be because Python 2 by default support only ASCII strings unless explicitly mentioned. To use Unicode instead of ASCII, you can add the following line on first line of your script:

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`